# Problem with my mc server created on google vps

Tags: minecraft

I have mc server and when I closing the console my server has stopping, What can I do to keep it active 24/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't suited for StackOverflow but more of [superuser](https://superuser.com/).

You can try using docker containers for the server.

You can do this on all platforms with docker desktop for windows

You can use the `screen` command on Linux.

It's also recommended to seek a Minecraft host.